# Model fit error pinching

Tags: error-analysis, statistics, models

I am performing a model function fit, $f=f(x,a,b)$, with the two parameters $\left\{a,b\right\}$ to be determined from the best fit to a set of data. In my determination of the resulting $1 \sigma$ error band I find that at some values of $x$ the error band pinches (that is the upper and lower boundary curves overlap). Physically, this makes no sense as it gives the impression that the error is identically zero at the overlap point. Is there anyway to provide a more physical estimate of the error?

I have the full correlation matrix in the space of my two parameters so in my estimate of the error I have included the correlation component in my analysis. 
The error on $f$ is then $$\sigma_f(x)^2 = \text{Cov($a,a$)}f_a^2 + \text{Cov($b,b$)}f_b^2 + 2\,\text{Cov($a,b$)}\,f_a f_b $$ with e.g $$f_a \equiv \left( \frac{ \partial f }{ \partial a }\right)|_{a_0,b_0}.$$ The pinching may be an artefact of the fact the two parameters $a$ and $b$ are basically anti-correlated but hopefully there is a way to estimate the error band with the correlations still in play.

Comment: Would [statistics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic I am happy for it to be moved there, whatever would be best

Comment: We could wait and see what the community thinks.

Comment: In order to answer the question, you have to provide the fitting function. E.g. the fitting function $f(x,a,b) = a x + b x^2$ satisfies $f(x=0, a, b)=0$ for all fit parameters $\{a, b\}$.

Comment: @Semoi the data appear over a certain range of x so I cannot fix x=0. At some value of x the error boundary curves overlap giving the pinch. The fit function is of the form $f(x,a,b) = ax^b.$

Comment: It is not unusual that such a function does not satisfy the constant variance assumption. Hence, the simplest work around -- it's actually not a work around, but statistically proper -- is to transform the data and use a different fitting function. I suggest you try a $log()$ transformation. Or, if you like to try more fancy stuff, use a Box-Cox transformation.